# How to check if graphviz-dev is installed on different Ubuntu versions?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I have a script installing graphviz-dev on my machines. The relevant line is `sudo apt install graphviz-dev`

In Ubuntu 16.04 it installs a package called graphviz-dev, and `dpkg -s graphviz-dev` will return a good response

However, on Ubuntu 18.04 it installs a different package - libgraphviz-dev, and now `dpkg -s graphviz-dev` won't work, but `dpkg -s libgraphviz-dev` would.

Is there a better way to check if the installation of said package (`graphviz-dev`) was successful, even if APT decided to redirect and install a different package instead?

Comment: It looks like [graphviz-dev is only a transitional package on 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphviz-dev) so perhaps you should be checking for `libgraphviz-dev` regardless

Comment: Cool, thx. However, this may be true for other packages I install. I can't list them all here, since the package list is updating from time to time, and so I'm looking for a robust solution

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see the [package description](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/graphviz) for `*graphviz-dev` is always the same (looked from 16.04 LTS to upcoming 20.04 LTS):

> graphviz libs and headers against which to build applications

so you can use simple `dpkg -l` with pipe and one-line scripting:

```
dpkg -l | grep "graphviz libs and headers" && \
echo "*graphviz-dev is installed :)" || echo "*graphviz-dev is not installed :("
```

For example on 16.04 LTS it will return:

> ii  libgraphviz-dev                               2.38.0-12ubuntu2.1                              amd64        graphviz libs and headers against which to build applications
>   *graphviz-dev is installed :)

---

You can install `*graphviz-dev` in universal way like below:

```
sudo apt-get install {lib,}graphviz-dev
```

Comment: The installation itself is covered, as apt install graphviz-dev will install correctly on 18.04. however working with the description seems flimsy IMO, because nothing ensures it's content